# Is there a way to upload an image and serve that image using mean.io nodeJS express?

Tags: node.js, express, mean.io

I have head that nodejs is not optimal for long running operations. however I would like my overall application to be based on mean.io (express and nodejs).  Even though node is not ideal for this operation since its long running, I would still like to use a nodejs module for uploading the image and serving it so i don't have multiple service technologies. I don't want to switch to Java or .net for this operation, just because its not an ideal nodejs task. Is there any reason node would not work for this?  In particular, how can I load images to folder belonging to a particular user in mean.io application? thanks

Comment: what are you using on the frontend part? I use express and node to upload multiple images in one go in specific folder for a user. Multer module of node might help you, there are other equally good modules as well out there.

Comment: Did you use Multer for this?  Also will it work for all types of images, jpeg, gif etc?

Comment: Please tell me what are you using for the frontend part. I used angularjs on frontend part and therefore I sent the files in an array format and the request was then made to Multer, all the images were uploaded in one go. Image formats wont be a problem and in fact you can upload other types of files as well, Multer doesn't care about your file type.

Answer (score -1):

User [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) . multer is a body parser for express.
To upload multiple files, user multer.any().

You express code should look like :

```
    var multer = require('multer');
    var multerObj= multer({dest : 'local folder dest'});
    app.use('/endpoint for upload/*',multerObj.any());

    //express code

   app.post('/endpoint for upload',function(req,res){
   //files cotain the file (binary) as well as the metadata related to the files.
    var files = req.files

  }
```

Comment: Seems like general purpose Asymc... Anything for uploading binary files in there?